# Not able to build ionic application, getting error: Command failed with exit code 2

Tags: ionic-framework

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
running cordova build android
Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" F:\ionic\myApp\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js F:\ionic\myApp
add to body class: platform-android
Running command: F:\ionic\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: F:\ionic\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: F:\ionic\myApp\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\svkaushik17\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Please let me know if there is any dependencies I've to install to build the application.

I've the Ionic website to build the app.

```
$ ionic platform add android
$ ionic build android
```

I also have installed the AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed this part of dependencies during the setup (Java Ant & Android on Windows).

It is available here: http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html

> Windows users developing for Android: You'll want to make sure you
>   have the following installed and set up.
>
> NOTE: Whenever you make changes to the PATH, or any other environment variable, you'll need to restart or open a new tab in your
>   shell program for the PATH change to take effect.
>
> Java JDK
>
> Install the most recent Java JDK (NOT just the JRE).
>
> Next, create an environment variable for JAVA_HOME pointing to the root folder where the Java JDK was installed. So, if you installed the
>   JDK into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7, set JAVA_HOME to be this path.
>   After that, add the JDK's bin directory to the PATH variable as well.
>   Following the previous assumption, this should be either
>   %JAVA_HOME%\bin or the full path C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7\bin
>
> Apache Ant
>
> To install Ant, download a zip from here, extract it, move the first folder in the zip to a safe place, and update your PATH to
>   include the bin folder in that folder. For example, if you moved the
>   Ant folder to c:/, you'd want to add this to your PATH:
>   C:\apache-ant-1.9.2\bin.
>
> Android SDK
>
> Installing the Android SDK is also necessary. The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build,
>   test, and debug apps for Android.
>
> Cordova requires the ANDROID_HOME environment variable to be set. This should point to the [ANDROID_SDK_DIR]\android-sdk directory (for
>   example c:\android\android-sdk).
>
> Next, update your PATH to include the tools/ and platform-tools/ folder in that folder. So, using ANDROID_HOME, you would add both
>   %ANDROID_HOME%\tools and %ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there isn't 2 versions of JDK installed. If you have 2 versions installed, try pointing your JAVA_HOME to the C:\Program Files\ version that seemed to resolve the issue. Also, cordova is checking for javac not just java -version, so try javac from command line and check if it works.